# Does River Song ever get jealous of the Doctor’s female companions?

Tags: doctor-who, river-song

River is well... psychotic. She was trained to kill the Doctor, frequently breaks out of prison and married the Doctor. Now the Doctor occasionally develops romantic feelings for his human companions like Grace and Rose. I would like to know if there is a canon event of her getting jealous of one of his companions?

Comment: This was a very different question when I misread it as "River Tam".

Answer (score 5):

**No, there is no canon instance of River Song displaying jealousy.**  While one can presume that she interacted with more than just the tenth and eleventh incarnations, and speculate that such interactions including interaction with a companion such as Rose Tyler with whom the doctor shared a relationship which was more romantic than platonic, such events have not and likely will not occur in canon.

---

Personally, I suspect that River Song would not be jealous of any companion, even one whom the Doctor became physically intimate with.  The connection the no-longer-as-psychotic River Song shared with her time lord paramour is unique in the domain of human-galafraian relations, and it would be highly unlikely that any comparable relation the Doctor ever had would not simply be an unforseen regeneration of Melody Pond.

Of course, that's entirely in the vein of non-canon theorizing and meta-speculation as to what some future show-runner might do with the characters.

Comment: `While one can presume that she interacted with more than just the tenth and eleventh incarnations` - I don't think we can assume that.  During 'Silence in the Library' she says something to the effect that this is the earliest version of the doctor she has ever met, and I assume you have watched and know what happens in 'Forest of the Dead'.

Comment: Go watch the episode again.  Her line was something like "it's weird when you go all baby-faced", implying it's happened before.  (That the Doctor didn't remember her is evidence for the other bit, but, well, rule #1.)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean 1996-movie Grace?

Well, the earliest the Doctor ever saw River Song was in *Silence in the Library/Forest of the Dead*, and his companion was Donna. He and Donna had, of course, a totally non-romantic relationship.

River wasn't there in the season 4 finale, so she's never met Rose. I'm sure she has heard about her, but since Rose is gone, River wouldn't feel jealous.

The only other companions that River has seen the Doctor with are Amy and Clara. Amy is River's mom, and River knows that Amy married Rory to have her, so of course River would not feel threatened.

Clara's relationship with the Doctor has been platonic so far. This may change in Season 8, but River hasn't indicated any jealousy yet.

Comment: Regardless if shes met the others she could know of them. Martha didnt know rose but was jealous of her anyway.